# IAudioClient->Initialize() fails with 0x80070016 - HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BAD_COMMAND) : The device does not recognize the command

Tags: c++, windows, wasapi

I am writing a WASAPI app. I have an external audio interface and the onboard Realtek audio card. I seem to have a problem running render devices in exclusive mode.

No matter what I do and what the user chooses, the app crashes on initialization. The culprit is `IAudioClient->Initialize()` that fails with the following code.

```
0x80070016 - HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BAD_COMMAND) : The device does not recognize the command
```

Here is the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <Functiondiscoverykeys_devpkey.h>
#include <vector>
#include <propvarutil.h>
#include <Audioclient.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Propsys.lib")

using namespace std;

// A device entry that the user can select from a menu.
struct device {
    WCHAR friendlyName[128];
    IMMDevice* pDevice;
};

int main()
{
    // Used for error codes.
    HRESULT hr;

    // Initialize COM.
    hr = CoInitialize(0);

    // The enumerator is used to list devices.
    IMMDeviceEnumerator* pEnumerator;
    const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
    const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
    hr = CoCreateInstance(
        CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator, NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL, IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        (void**)&pEnumerator);

    // We only care about render devices.
    vector<device> renderDevices;

    // We enumerate them.
    IMMDeviceCollection* pRenderCollection;
    hr = pEnumerator->EnumAudioEndpoints(eRender, DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE, &pRenderCollection);
    UINT cRenderDevices;
    hr = pRenderCollection->GetCount(&cRenderDevices);
    for (UINT i = 0; i < cRenderDevices; i++) {
        // For each device, we create a device entry.
        device dev;

        // We store the pointer to the device in dev.pDevice.
        hr = pRenderCollection->Item(i, &dev.pDevice);

        // We store the friendly name in dev.friendlyName;
        IPropertyStore* pProperties;
        hr = dev.pDevice->OpenPropertyStore(STGM_READ, &pProperties);
        PROPVARIANT friendlyName;
        hr = pProperties->GetValue(PKEY_Device_FriendlyName, &friendlyName);
        hr = PropVariantToString(friendlyName, dev.friendlyName, 128);
        renderDevices.push_back(dev);
        pProperties->Release();
    }
    pRenderCollection->Release();

    // We don't need the enumerator anymore.
    pEnumerator->Release();

    // We let the user pick a device.
    int renderIndex;
    cout << "Select render device" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < renderDevices.size(); i++) {
        wcout << "  " << i << ") " << renderDevices[i].friendlyName << endl;
    }
    cin >> renderIndex;

    // And that's what we are going to use.
    IMMDevice* pRenderDevice = renderDevices[renderIndex].pDevice;

    // We activate the device to get an audio client.
    IAudioClient* pAudioRenderClientTemp;
    hr = pRenderDevice->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioClient), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&pAudioRenderClientTemp);

    // We want to get a suitable format for each mode of operation, exclusive and shared.
    WAVEFORMATEX* pExclusiveRenderFormat = NULL;
    WAVEFORMATEX* pSharedRenderFormat = NULL;

    // This is the target format that we are interested in.
    WAVEFORMATEX format;
    format.wFormatTag = WAVE_FORMAT_PCM;
    format.nChannels = 2;
    format.cbSize = 0;
    format.wBitsPerSample = 16;
    format.nBlockAlign = format.nChannels * format.wBitsPerSample / 8;
    format.nSamplesPerSec = 44100;
    format.nAvgBytesPerSec = format.nSamplesPerSec * format.nBlockAlign;

    // This variable will store the closest match.
    WAVEFORMATEX* pClosestMatch;

    // We try to get a shared mode format.
    pClosestMatch = NULL;

    if (S_OK == pAudioRenderClientTemp->IsFormatSupported(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED, &format, &pClosestMatch)) {
        cout << "Exact format match for shared mode." << endl;
        pSharedRenderFormat = &format;
    }
    else if (pClosestMatch) {
        cout << "Close match for shared mode." << endl;
        pSharedRenderFormat = pClosestMatch;
    }

    // We try to get an exclusive mode format.
    pClosestMatch = NULL;

    if (S_OK == pAudioRenderClientTemp->IsFormatSupported(AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE, &format, &pClosestMatch)) {
        cout << "Exact format match for exclusive mode." << endl;
        pExclusiveRenderFormat = &format;
    }
    else if (pClosestMatch) {
        cout << "Close format match for exclusive mode." << endl;
        pExclusiveRenderFormat = pClosestMatch;
    }

    // We give precedence to exclusive mode if available.
    auto renderMode = pExclusiveRenderFormat ? AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_EXCLUSIVE : AUDCLNT_SHAREMODE_SHARED;
    auto renderFormat = pExclusiveRenderFormat ? pExclusiveRenderFormat : pSharedRenderFormat;

    // We try to initialize the device; no matter what the user chooses, this fails with
    // 0x80070016 - HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BAD_COMMAND) : The device does not recognize the command.
    hr = pAudioRenderClientTemp->Initialize(
        renderMode,
        0,
        1000,
        0,
        renderFormat,
        NULL);
    
    return hr;
}
```

Here is the console output when picking the integrated soundcard.

```
Select render device
  0) Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)
  1) Speakers (USB Audio CODEC )
0
Close match for shared mode.
Exact format match for exclusive mode.
```

And here is the console output when picking the external audio interface.

```
Select render device
  0) Speakers (Realtek(R) Audio)
  1) Speakers (USB Audio CODEC )
1
Exact format match for shared mode.
Exact format match for exclusive mode.
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit #1**

I tried [this app](https://gist.github.com/mhamilt/859e57f064e4d5b2bb8e78ae55439d70) and on my system it fails in the same way as mine. What's wrong with my system? Maybe Windows 11 does not support WASAPI in console apps? What's going on?

**Edit #2**

I tried to copy my code in a WinMain and the same thing happens; all S_OK, one S_FALSE when checking for format support, which still results into a valid closest format match and then the same error `0x80070016 - HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(ERROR_BAD_COMMAND)` when I call Initialize.

**Edit #3 (I rebooted the system and it works)**

Okay, so I noticed that even the Test Sounds button in Windows in Chrome and YouTube were not working, even though I was not getting any error. Then I remembered that on this PC I frequently have audio issues. So, I rebooted and of course now everything seems to be working. It may not be a StackOverflow question after all; maybe it's more for SuperUser. *Why is audio so finicky*?

Comment: One thing you're not doing is checking the values of hr for possible failures.

Comment: I checked all of them using the debugger, and they are all S_OK, except the result of IsFormatSupported which is S_FALSE; but that one, in case of failure, should still produce a closest match, so I should be good; but maybe I misunderstood the docs.